# Creating and populating a primary key column in an existing table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Question**

I am not 100% sure on how to create a column in an existing table which can act as a unique primary key and would like verification as to whether my approach below would work and advice/ suggestions on perhaps a better way if applicable of doing it.

**Scenario**

Say I have an existing table (`tbl_employee`) shown below

```
Employee Name    Location
------------------------------
John              London
Sharath           New York
Nivas             Mumbai
Praveen           Texas
Maharaj           Las Vegas
```

I want to add a column to this table which can act as an primary key and look something like this

```
EmployeeID
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
```

***Tried***

Creating a column to the table, assigning that column as the primary key. Not sure if this would work as intended? Verifcation/ potential suggestions on improvement would be appreciated.

```
-- Purpose of this is to add an EmployeeID to the existing table (values such as shown above)
-- Set the EmployeeID as the primary key of the table (no primary key already exists)

ALTER TABLE tbl_employee ADD EmployeeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_employee_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeID);
```

Comment: Do you have any particular column to order the employee_id?

Comment: You can add an `IDENTITY` to a table after you have created it yes. Just remember that the value assigned to each row will be completely arbitrary. As you *imply* have no `CLUSTERED INDEX` on your table, at the moment then the data is stored in a unordered heap.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah I don't have an actual column to order the EmployeeID. Is this an issue? Would you be able to create an answer which perhaps explains this further? Am fairly new to SQL.

Comment: You need to be clear what kind of validation you want (if any)? For example if somebody tries to add another employee called John, do you want it to just create a new employeeID for that row (even if it may be a duplicate record for existing employee), or fail as a primary key violation?

Comment: Sure, I think in this scenario I would like it to just create a new EmployeeID but would like to know what it would look like to make this fail as a primary key violation too. The example I have shown is an over simplification in-order to ease of understanding of problem. Perhaps though that has led to ambiguity.

Comment: Most tables have something to uniquely identify a row in it - apart from some identity column. If this is an employee table, it will probably contain an employee number or the like, well something to identify an employee in the real world (which can also be the name plus birthdate for instance). You are adding a technical unique ID, but you should also make sure that the natural key (the employee number or whatever) has a unique constraint. Most DBMS use a unique index on the column(s) to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Ok cool thanks, I am guessing then adding a unique constraint to an already existing column can be done in a similar fashion (`ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_employee 
ADD EmployeeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_employee_EmployeeID  PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_employee
ADD EmployeeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE tbl_employee
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_employee_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID);
```

And

To create an index, use the following command instead of using `CLUSTERED` in the column definition

```
CREATE INDEX idx__tbl_employee_EmployeeID
ON tbl_employee (EmployeeID);
```

finally

Add a column as the **primary key** with the **Identity** property and create an **index** for it in one place.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_employee ADD EmployeeID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_tbl_employee_EmployeeID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EmployeeID)
```

Comment: There is no need to create an index if the column is declared as the primary key.  It gets its own index, as does any `unique` column.

Comment: I did not see any indication of indexing in the automatic scripts I got from the definition of the table in SQL when defining the primary key. That is, there is a difference in the appearance of the definition of the table, even if it is not needed.